# EditText scroll horizontal while adding text using Button

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext, horizontal-scrolling

I have made a simple button which adds number "1" in an EditText.

Here is the XML code

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"   
    android:onClick="Btn1"
/>
```

And the Java code

```
public void Btn1(View v){
    EditText edittext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
    String getText = edittext1.getText().toString();
    show_results.setText(getText+"1");
}
```

When I write in `EditText` with keyboard it automatically scrolls horizontally and shows the last character. But when I press the button it adds the text but doesn't scroll (so only first characters are visible).

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: You want to scroll the View??

Comment: @Naddy It is not a View. It is EditText

Comment: Correct your basics mate. EditText extends TextView which extends View. Anyway you want to scroll EditText? It'snot clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public void Btn1(View v){
    EditText edittext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
    String getText = edittext1.getText().toString();
    show_results.setText(getText+"1"); // not really sure what show_results is,
                                       // but I suppose it's another EditText
    show_results.setSelection(edittext1.getText().length());
}
```

Comment: 'setSelection': http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#setSelection(int) which leads to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection.html#setSelection(android.text.Spannable, int) which states 'Move the cursor to offset index.' - I might have understood you question wongly but I tought that you want your cursor at the end of the inserted text (even if you have a fixed height for your edit text, the view will always scroll - I edited the answer to be mode specific)